# Chisel, Generate Blocks and Large Intermediate/Output Files

Tags: hdl, chisel, loop-unrolling

Is there a construct in Chisel to generate Verilog `generate` blocks instead of unrolling Scala for-loops into *very* large (>100k line) output Verilog and FIRRTL files.

For example, I have the following code, that constructs a 2D lattice of `MatrixElement` modules and connects their inputs and outputs.

```
private val mat_elems = Seq.tabulate(rows, cols) { (i, j) => {
    Module(new MatrixElement(n=i, m=j))
}}

for (i <- 0 until rows; j <- 0 until cols) {
    // Wavefront propagation
    if (i == 0 && j != 0) {
      // First row
      mat_elems(i)(j).io.in <> (false.B, false.B, mat_elems(i)(j - 1).io.out)
    } else if (i != 0 && j == 0) {
      // First col
      mat_elems(i)(j).io.in <> (false.B, mat_elems(i - 1)(j).io.out, false.B)
    } else if (i >= 1 && j >= 1) {
      // Internal matrix
      mat_elems(i)(j).io.in <> (mat_elems(i - 1)(j - 1).io.out, mat_elems(i - 1)(j).io.out,
        mat_elems(i)(j - 1).io.out)
    }
  }
```

I am looking to compile this code for values of `rows` and `cols` >= 256. So this matrix gets very large in size.

If I were writing this as Verilog module, I would make use of `generate` blocks. However, in Chisel, since I am using the Scala loops, the entire lattice/matrix gets unrolled in the FIRRTL/Verilog outputs. Often producing >100k lines with all the `_T*` wires for 512x512 lattices. This causes a whole bunch of JVM out of memory errors in the Chisel compilation and makes the VCS simulation (just parsing the files takes forever) of the output files *VERY* slow.

Is there any way around this? Maybe get Chisel to generate Verilog `generate` blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support in Chisel nor FIRRTL for compressing this. Such a feature would probably be pretty useful but we have no plan or timeline for it. You can always use a blackbox and write the Verilog to do it yourself if you find the compilation time saved to be worth it.